# How can I control my winmo phone?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, activesync

I have been trying to find a way to control my winmo phone from my pc. (HTC S740)

What I want is to be able to call a number from an application, answer the phone from an application and hangup the phone from an application. It should also be able to track how long the ongoing call has been.

Any libraries out there that lets me make such an application with C#?

(The phone is connected to the pc via usb in Windows 7.)

Comment: What have you found in your search so far? A quick google search turned up [Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Telephony](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa455392.aspx). Have you looked at that?

Comment: That's the wrong end. I want to control it via the PC. That's a Windows Mobile SDK api...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RAPI to invoke functionality on the device. You might need to write a wrapper.
I believe that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542287/desktop-to-windows-mobile-communication/542324#542324) by ctacke should help you perform the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at OpenNETCF library, which have many utilities to call native APIs that can help you, but i didn't hear of any library to help control your phone remotely.